# How to place dotfill and droppoints on the same line

Tags: exam, mhchem

I have these codes

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\pointsdroppedatright
\setlength\dottedlinefillheight{1cm}
\begin{questions}
\question
Complete the following equations and write the I.U.P.A.C names of the main 
organic product in each case. 
\begin{parts}
\part[01 mark] 
\ce{CH3CH=CH2 ->[\ce{MnO4 \mch[] / OH \mch[]}]} 
\fillwithdottedlines{1cm} \droppoints 
Name of product \fillwithdottedlines{1cm} \droppoints 
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it gives the image below.

[image]

What I need is given below.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \fillwithdottedlines command inserts dotted lines BELOW the text.

Could be like that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
    \pointsdroppedatright
    \setlength\dottedlinefillheight{1cm}
    \begin{questions}
        \question
        Complete the following equations and write the I.U.P.A.C names of the main 
        organic product in each case. 
        \begin{parts}
            \part[01 mark] 
            \ce{CH3CH=CH2 ->[\ce{MnO^{-}_{4} / OH-}]} \dotfill
            
            Name of product \dotfill
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]